# Add reference to a single DLL file

Tags: c#, dotnet-cli

I would like to add a reference to `/path/to/lib.dll` using the .NET CLI. All the results on google tell me how to add a *project* reference, but I want to add a single DLL file that is not in a project. I know how to do this in Visual studio, but how do I do it from the command-line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit your `.csproj` and add:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="MyAssembly">
    <HintPath>path\to\MyAssembly.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

and then `dotnet restore`

Reference: https://medium.com/@tonerdo/referencing-a-net-dll-directly-using-the-net-core-toolchain-16f0af46a4dc